# Determining a meter-based SRID

Tags: arcgis-desktop, srid, afghanistan

I have a set of shapefiles (Kabul, Afghanistan) that are currently in the WGS84 geographic coordinate system (GEOGCS), which I believe has a SRID of 4326.  In ArcMap, this coordinate system is decimal digit based.  How would I determine the appropriate meters-based coordinate system for this set of shapefiles, and thereby a meters-based SRID for this set of shapefiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a shapefile in your Arc install location Desktop10.1\Reference Systems called UTM.shp, refer to that for the zone and use WGS84 UTM Zone XX (North) because you are north of the equator, replace XX with the zone number from the shapefile. This will be compatible with your geographic coordinate system and will project easily.

As a SRID all WGS84/UTM projections start with 326 for North and 327 for south and then insert the zone number:

Zone 28 North is 32628

Zone 30 South is 32730

UTM should work well for you around one city or province, if you want to see more than a few degrees you should consider an Albers Equal Area or Lamberts Conformal Conic projection based on the WGS84 spheroid; that's quite an advanced topic which you may need to post when you know the area to be covered if you can't work out how the parameters go.